gitlab An error occurred while fetching commit data
I installed the gitlab and moved the repositories from the bitbucket to it. The gitflow branch system.
In all brunches in which the name has "/", for example featch/ or bag/, etc., an error is displayed as in the screenshot, as well as it is impossible to make a merge request from these brunches.
The official documentation of gitlab says that it's about an ad blocker https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/troubleshooting.html#:~:text=When%20you%20visit%20a%20project,you%20are%20trying%20to%20access, but this is not the case.
Please tell me which logs to look at and how to find the source of the problem.
The data about the gitlab version is on the second screenshot. https://i.sstatic.net/Wir4it2w.png
I also checked the "/" symbol in the corresponding version, it is not prohibited in branches names.  Сhecked other brunch names with different symbols "%@$*_-ˆ" everything is fine there.
I tried to understand the cause of the problem and reduced it to the / symbol in the names of the brunches, I do not understand that this cannot be true, since such a name is used in gitflow.
https://i.sstatic.net/0br0lU9C.png

The problem was in the reverse proxy settings, in my case it was Apache.
  ServerAdmin [redacted]
  ServerName [redacted]

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/[redacted]_access_log combined
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/[redacted]_error_log

AllowEncodedSlashes On # <-- add this line
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:[docker_port]/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:[docker_port]/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[redacted]/privkey.pem
  SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
</VirtualHost>

